# Can't redirect using urls patterns

Tags: django

When i try go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/1395ec37e4/ i get error: Page not found at ...
I don't know why, twice, when i had changed variable getted_short_url to short_urlin urls.py and views.py(redirect_view) it could redirect me. I am confused...

**Log from page:**

```
Using the URLconf defined in cut_and_go.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
     <str:getted_short_url>
     admin/

The current path, 1395ec37e4/, didn't match any of these.
```

**views.py:**

```
from hashlib import sha256

from .models import URL
from .forms import URLInput
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


def input_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = URLInput(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            getted_url = form.cleaned_data["full_url"]
            transformed_url = 'https://' + getted_url
            try:
                URL.objects.get(full_url=transformed_url)
            except URL.DoesNotExist:
                maked_url = sha256(transformed_url.encode()).hexdigest()[:10]
                URL(full_url=transformed_url, short_url=maked_url).save()
    else:
        form = URLInput()
    return render(request, 'shortener/input_form.html', {'form': form})


def redirect_view(request, getted_short_url):
    return redirect(URL.get_full_url(getted_short_url))
```

**urls.py:**

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.input_form),
    path('<str:getted_short_url>', views.redirect_view)
]
```

Comment: Try `'<str:getted_short_url>/'` (Note the _trailing_ slash `/`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `str` path converter does not catch the `/` character at the end of your URL. If you want to match only the part before the `/`, add a 2nd urlpattern (or replace the existing one if you don't care about URLs not ending with `/`) that includes the `/` at the end. If you want to catch this trailing slash in your path argument, use `path` instead of `str`. See [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) for more information.